# Promotion engine for POS- Self Checkout

Tags: rule-engine, discount, pos

I wish to make a promotion engine for retail systems connected to a central system. So when items are added in a cart, a promotion offer should get automatically applied based on the items added.
For Example, Buy 2 items A, and 1 item of B, offer applied Buy1 Get2 Free.
Now item A, item B are groups of few items.
One of the way I can go by is hitting a API, Every time cart is updated, and then checking which rule is satisfied, but I don't want that way to go. I want to make it work in real time without hitting API.
Please help me suggest the best possible way to do it.
Thanks

Comment: What you are saying is a business idea, not a programming problem/issue. This site is not a place for development requests or consulting, so it will be an off-topic. Please refer to this help article and move to a suitable place or change it to a suitable content. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @kunif I am concerned about the techstack or code that I can use for this feature